# Taking screenshot of OneNote page with REST API

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm using `GET ~/pages/{id}/content` API with headless browser to make snapshot of OneNote page but I just realised this API doesn't give Ink contents. - https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/5657688-ink-support-in-the-api

Is there any other way to get page content include Inks?

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote API does not currently support extracting or writing ink to it. There is a UserVoice entry for this that you might want to upvote and/or follow.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/5657688-ink-support-in-the-api

As a personal opinion, I think it would make sense to expose ink from the OneNote API as InkML.